# Basic operator overloading in D (Part 2)

Tags: syntax, compiler-errors, operator-overloading, d

Using Tango with D1:

```
class C 
{
    private int j;
    public int opBinary(char[] op: "+") (ref C x) { return 1; }
    public int opBinary(char[] op: "+") (C x) { return 3; }
}

int opBinary(char[] op: "+") (ref C x, ref C y) { return 2; }
int opBinary(char[] op: "+") (C x, C y) { return 2; }

void main() {
    C a = new C;
    C b = new C;

    int j = a + b;
}
```

Compiler error:

> "incompatible types"

meaning the overloaded operators weren't matched.

Can't wait to get the hang of D.

Thanks much.

OH Yea:  I'm using Tango with D1, so maybe that's why it's not working?  I'd like to stick with Tango.  Has anyone used Tango + D2?

Comment: Someone needs to make a D++ so google will come up with the right search results.

Comment: A couple of useful links for you: http://dlang.org/operatoroverloading.html#Binary and https://github.com/SiegeLord/Tango-D2

Comment: The recommended approach is to google for "D programming".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In D1 templated operator overloading using opBinary, etc. doesn't work.  You need to use [opAdd, opSub, etc.](http://digitalmars.com/d/1.0/operatoroverloading.html)